# Can I created nested discovery rules in Zabbix?

Tags: monitoring, zabbix, redis

I have installed Zabbix for monitoring some machines I'm responsible for. A few hosts in this setup run multiple redis instances running on different ports and each instance has multiple databases. I have a template that uses low-level discovery rules to figure out which databases in a given redis instance are active and it can then monitor the `key_space_db_expires` and `key_space_db_keys` values.

What I want now is to be able to auto-discover the redis instances running on each host and then monitor all the configured item along with the items which have to be monitored per database and need to be discovered per instance. The documentation doesn't show any way to do it through the UI. I can try it out by modifying the XML (a bit tedious) of the template but wanted to know if someone has already tried this and save me some labour.

Answer (score 1):

not with low level discovery, although maybe new host discovery in 2.2 works for that